# Position of a plane that intersects point

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d, plane-geometry

I'm trying to find the position of a plane such that it intersects an arbitrary point.

A point **P** exists along a vector **M** starting at **O**, a plane intersects **P** with a normal vector of **N**.

What is the position of **P** such that the plane intersects another point **Q**.

[image: diagram]

For the purposes of this problem you can think of **O** as being the origin and that both **Q**, **M** and **N** are known.

This problem has had me stumped for a while now and is vital to a personal project I'm working on. I'd like to understand the theory better so I don't get stuck like this again so any input as to what to study would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So -1 without a reason, very nice. I guess this forum is only for solving peoples homework for them. Might aswell call it homework exchange.

Comment: Assuming $p$ is a multiple of $m$, the plane's equation is $\langle n,x\rangle - \langle n,\lambda m\rangle=0$.  Now for $q$  being a member of that plane we get $$\lambda=\frac{\langle n,q\rangle}{\langle n,m\rangle},$$ provided that $\langle n,m\rangle\neq0$.

Comment: thank you for your help, but I'm not familiar with your nomenclature, what would $\langle n,q\rangle$ represent?

Comment: $\langle .,.\rangle$ represents the product.

Comment: You should study multi-variable calculus. The -1 was for lack of effort. Rather than saying what you tried, you said you have been stumped for a while and the answer is important to you. Study multi-variable calculus and you will be able to do these yourself.

Comment: @JohnDouma Then you should probably -1 every post on this forum, clearly they should study X and never post a question. Not everyone knows even where to begin to find a solution, out of all my old math books only one had any mention of equations of a plane and thanks to Michael I was able to find that section. I specifically mentioned I did not know what to even study so I think your -1 and comment are not only unwarranted and toxic but invalidate the purpose of this forum.

Comment: @bob3d That's not true. Many folks on this site work very hard and articulate exactly where they are stuck. If you give them hints, they work through the problems. They are a joy to work with and they are why I participate on this forum. You, on the other hand, just posted a problem and your comments show indignity, not effort. You seem to think we owe you a solution because you really want one.

Comment: @JohnDouma So you're saying I did not meet some bar of work you expect before you would consider offering help and instead met a bar where you would engage in toxic behaviour. Well apologies for a non academic posting a math question in a math forum and far from indignity I'm thankful that at least some people have their arrogance in check enough to actually want to offer help rather than serve some dubious ego stroking exercise. I really don't understand users like you.

Comment: @bob3d How is it toxic behavior to point out why you received a downvote? Your question stated "I'd like to understand the theory better so I don't get stuck like this again so any input as to what to study would be greatly appreciated.". I then said that you should study multi-variable calculus. You criticized the name of this forum for the downvote and are now accusing me of being toxic for answering your question. Your label of "toxic" seems to be common to all of those who refuse to work and expect everyone to indulge them.

Comment: @JohnDouma Your problem is that you seem to have an ego complex that makes you think you solely represent some collective and that the requisite amount of grovelling should be endured before any information is shared. You also seem to think that "study multi-variable calculus" and a zero context downvote is constructive. Two other users actually provided constructive information, you did not. In each of your comments you found ways to instead mock me for daring to ask a question at all. Clearly you have no interest in constructive dialogue but instead find pleasure in being toxicly unpleasant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal vector $N$ to the plane is known, and the point $Q$ which lies on the plane is known, therefore, the equation of the plane is

$ N \cdot (r - Q) = 0 $

Now point $P = \lambda M $ for some known vector $M$

Plug that in the equation of the plane,

$ N \cdot ( \lambda M - Q ) = 0 $

Solving for $\lambda$, one gets

$ \lambda = \dfrac{N \cdot Q} { N \cdot M } $

Now point $P$ is fully specified.